# How to add and use a Div as a total calculator using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a function which calculates the sum of a users input and compare it to a previously given value, returning the result to the user.

e.g. You previously said you eat 20 meals a week but you have currently listed 5 Dinners, 7 Lunches and 36 Breakfasts. This totals 48 meals.

So far I can read my inputs and add them to a variable as the respondent types it in, showing this in an already existing div. But I need to create a div to show it in for it's actual use. This is where I'm having problems as I can't get this code working.

Note I'm new to JS so some of my code might make no sense. This is everything I've got so far, the bit commented out is what is causing trouble, the rest (assuming I have a div ID'd as 'output') works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var count = 0;
    function summer() {
        var num1 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("number1").value)) || 0;
        var num2 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("number2").value)) || 0;
        var num3 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("number3").value)) || 0;
        count = num1+num2+num3;
     // if(!document.getElementById("output")) {
     //     var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
     //     var divIdName = 'output';
     //     var myDiv = document.getElementById('buttoner');
     //     var content = document.createTextNode("")
     //     newDiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
     //     newDiv.appendChild(content);
     //     document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, myDiv)
     //     };
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Your running total = "+count
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="number1" onKeyUp="summer()" name="number" />
<input type="text" id="number2" onKeyUp="summer()" name="number" />
<input type="text" id="number3" onKeyUp="summer()" name="number" />
<div id='Buttoner'>
<button type="button" onclick="summer()">Clicking here adds your input to the "count" variable</button>
</div>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

edit: thought it might be worth noting that the 'buttoner' div is left over from a previous stage of experimenting and is now used as a placemarker for inserting the new div.

Comment: The code worked fine, I was just running it in W3schools which apparently is crap. thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q65BT/

```
var pre =0;
var count = 0;
function summer(a) {
    var num1 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("number1").value)) || 0;
    var num2 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("number2").value)) || 0;
    var num3 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("number3").value)) || 0;
    if(a==1)
    {
    pre=count;
    count = num1+num2+num3;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You previously said you eat "+pre+" meals a week but you have currently listed "+num1+" Dinners, "+num2+" Lunches and "+num3+" Breakfasts. This totals "+count+" meals.";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Same as above though, I got the adding function working just fine. But I need to be able to create a div to add it into (due to not being able to do it in the programme I'm using). The problem is the commented out bit which doesn't work for me at all.

Annoyingly enough I just tried my code in JSfiddle and it worked perfectly. Not using W3Schools again.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems quite simple to me. If that is really all your HTML, your only problem is you don't have the `output` div.

You can solve this in some ways. Using pure JavaScript...

```
var output = document.createElement("div"); // Creates a <div> element
output.innerHTML = "Your running total = " + count;
document.body.appendChild(output); // Add the <div> to the end of the <body>
```

Another way is to put the `output` div in the HTML, this way you won't even need to change your script:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

If you want the `output` not to be visible before the input, you can CSS it a little...

```
<div id="output" style="display: none;"></div>
```

And make it visible with Javascript whenever you want.

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
output.style.display = 'block'; // or 'inline-block', or 'inline', etc. See what fits you better
```

As you're beginnning with Javascript, I'd recommend you start in the right path by reading on unobstrusive Javascript. I can update the answer with some unobstrusive JS if you want.

**UPDATE**: If you want to substitute the `button` `div` with the new `output` `div`, you can simply change the names from `output` to `button` / `buttoner` / `whatever you want`.

**UPDATE 2**: Seems like I didn't understand your question correctly. If you want to store the previous answer, you can do it in a variety of ways as well.

One is to store the current answer in a hidden field. For example...

```
<input type="hidden" id="prevAnswer" value="0" />
```

Then, in your Javascript, you can do it like this:

```
var prevAnswer = document.getElementById("prevAnswer")
var prevAnswerValue = parseFloat(prevAnswer.value) || 0;
output.innerHTML = "You previously said you eat " + prevAnswerValue + " meals a week but you have currently listed " + num1 + " Dinners, " + num2 + " Lunches and " + num3 + " Breakfasts. This totals " + count + " meals.";
prevAnswer.value = count;
```

So you will always have the Previous Answer whenever you calculate a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the response! For the first two parts, I'm aware that I could just place in an output div right into the code, but the programme I'm using generates it's own html which I won't be able to affect in such a direct manner (or at least I don't know how). I can however manipulate it with javascript which is why I need to use javascript to insert a new div instead of manipulating one that is already there.

Comment: Got it. As I said, take a read on Unobstrusive Javascript since you're a beginner: you'll see you can do plenty of stuff in better ways, and also avoids your code becoming spaghetti as it grows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what behavior you are missing.  When I uncomment that block, it **[seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/bBw4z/)**.  The new DIV is being created on the fly if it didn't already exist.

The code is wordier than necessary, but if as you say, you're a beginner, this is not a bad thing.  Here's some possible clean-up:

```
if (!document.getElementById("output")) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'output');
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('buttoner');
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, myDiv)
};
```

Comment: Well, that's the hard way to learn, but you probably won't forget it!